# AdminLTE footer issu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some issue when i use AdminLTE,

the footer became to long in firefox when the data in table is not full.

but nothing happen the same to chrome.

maybe you guys had the same problem with can share some information about it.

here's the screenshot:

in firefox
[image]

in chrome
[image]